# app is not defined in appBuilder

Tags: telerik, telerik-appbuilder

I added a view to my Telerik AppBuilder I added a javascript file to index.html and added the view myview.html when I run the view I get 'app is not defined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and make sure the javascript for your view was not added in index.html before the app.js

Note: After pulling my hair out I wanted to record this for someone else to find. Simple solution but it would have saved me some time if I would have the answer.

Comment: Its just 4min difference of asking a question and posting answer your self. :D How can that save your time ?

Comment: I already had the solution when I posted the question ... but I wanted to document it